# Adding a raster layer on map canvas in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgsmapcanvas

```
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.show()
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('testdata/airports.shp', "Airports layer", "ogr")
canvas.setExtent(vlayer.extent())
canvas.setLayers([vlayer])

tms = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'
layer = QgsRasterLayer(tms,'OSM', 'wms')
canvas.setLayers([layer ])
```

Above code works fine with vector layer but when I am trying to `QgsRasterLayer`
show cyan colour.

[image]

How can I add raster layer on map canvas?

Comment: please add the code where you create the raster layer

Comment: @BenW after I modified code raster shows cyan color only

Comment: You need to delete the first canvas.setLayers() and add vlayer to the second one like this "canvas.setLayers([vlayer,layer])"
You raster is cyan because I think you're in the water, your vlayer (wich is your extent) must be in Mercator (EPSG:3857) for your map to focus at the right location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That cyan color is probably The Atlantic Ocean. Try the following way. It worked for me.

```
test_data = 'testdata/airports.shp'

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(test_data, "test", "ogr")
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)

tms = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'
layer = QgsRasterLayer(tms,'OSM', 'wms')

canvas.setLayers([vlayer, layer])
canvas.setExtent(vlayer.extent())

canvas.show()
```

[image]